# IP addresses not listed for IIS website bindings

Tags: windows, iis, binding, ip

Recently purchased a windows cloud server godaddy. Now i installed iis7 and all other required software. And i have 50.62.1.89 and 2 more public ips. Also i have a private ip 10.1.0.2. Now the problem is am unable to access any website through any public ip. All my public ips are opening default website only. also i cant see pubic ips for IIS website bindings. Only my private ip listed for IIS binding.

And in my server also public opening only default website. But am able to open websites using private ip. But my public ip addresses pointed to my server correctly. am able to open my server using remote desktop using public ip. Also as i said already public ip opening default website from IIS without problem.

Please help me. Am confused for last 2 days.

Comment: Not a programming question, should be on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

You should review GoDaddy documentation (or ask GoDaddy support) on how your cloud servers should be configured:

- private IP addresses are non-routable on the internet
- If you only see private IP addresses (10.x.x.x) on your server (as configured by GoDaddy) then that means there is a "routing system" (nlb, firewall, etc.) that routes your public IPs to your private IPs - that's the only way you can "browse to your web site using a public IP" - there is a NAT (translator) that maps the public IPs to your private IP/s (and ports).

Answer (score 0):

The bindings in IIS should use the internal IP.  You will either have Port Forwarding Rules or Load Balancing Rules that take the external IP and translate it to the internal IP.  Once translated the virtual machines will use the internal IP for everything, including bindings in IIS.  When the request leaves the server the request will be translated back to the external IP.

Here is the steps to set up IIS for a working website:

1. Create or have an already working network in Go Daddy Cloud Server Console.
2. Create a windows VM
3. Under Start
4. Administrative Tools
5. Server Manager
6. Roles
7. Web Server IIS
8. Right click sites
9. Add Website
10. Site name: mysite.com
11. Physical Path: choose path to where you website will live on the filesystem. This example we will create and use: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.com`
12. Binding: All Unassigned Port 80
13. Hostname mysite.com
14. Click Ok
15. Right click mysite.com
16. Edit Bindings
17. Add
18. host name: www.mysite.com
19. Click ok
20. Add your content to: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.com`
21. From the Go Daddy Cloud Server console add a port forward to a public IP, please see:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/6197

At this point, if you go to yourpublicIP you will see the IIS7 welcome page.  This is because this IP is owned by the Default site in IIS.

If you already have the domain pointed to your public IP, ie mysite.com resolves to yourpublicIPaddress, then visiting mysite.com will work in your web browser.

If you do not have the DNS pointed to the public IP, you can edit the hosts file on your local machine to cause the domain to resolve to that IP *ON YOUR MACHINE ONLY*:

For paths see:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/3354/viewing-your-website-before-changing-your-nameservers-using-host-files

Add an entry on a single line like: mysite.com 50.62.1.89

Save and close the file.

Close your web browser, reopen, and now go to mysite.com.  It should work as expected.

Using the above method you can place as many websites as you want on the 50.62.1.89 IP address.

If you want a website to *own* everything for that IP Address.

1. Start
2. Administrative tools
3. Server Manager
4. Roles
5. Web Server IIS
6. Right click mysite.com
7. Edit Bindings
8. Add
9. IP Address: 10.1.0.2
10. Ok

Now Going to yourpublicIPaddress will show your website.

Comment: Now if you have mutliple websites say:

mysite.com on publicIP1
myawesomesite.com publicIP2
mysuperawesomesite.com publicIP3

and you want each one of these to *own* its own Public IP address

Choose 10.1.1.2 port 81 for myawesomesite.com and port 82 for mysuperawesomesite.com.

Comment: 1. Name: myawesomesite.com
 2. Public IP: publicIP2
 3. Public Port: 80
 4. Destination port: 81
 5. Click ok
 6. In your windows VM, Start 
 7. Administrative Tools 
 8. Server Manager 
 9. Roles 
 10. Web Server IIS
 11. Right click myawesomesite.com 
 12. Edit Bindings
 13. Add
 14. IP Address: 10.1.0.2 port 81
 15. Hostname: www.myawesomesite.com
 16. OK
 17. Click Add again
 18. IP Address: 10.1.0.2 port 81
 19. OK




Repeat the hosts step if needed, but myawesomesite.com should work via both IP address and hostname.

Comment: Note: this last method is a waste of IP address and not recommended *unless* you have SSL Certificates, in which case, it is required.

Comment: Thanks.  You guys should put this somewhere on Godaddy's sites.   Question, when Windows Server 2012 comes out, which allows SSL certs under one Ip address, will we be able to upgrade our Windows 2008 R2 Servers for free?   Godaddy cloud servers are good, but $5 per ip is sorta steep.

Also wish you guys would allow exporting and importing of godaddy cloud servers in and out.  Being able to configure or backup the images locally is great.  Also being able to export the XEN images into a Godaddy Dedicated server would be GOLD!

Comment: Frank,
When(I am not sure on the exact timeline for this) we start to offer support for Server 2012 it will be that you spin up a new server with Server 2012 and then discontinue your old servers you no longer wish to use.  Even if Server 2012 supports many SSL Certificates per IP, the issue is that it requires newer browsers in order to work correctly.  It is not 100% server side.  Until all the old browsers are updated to support this, you will not see wide spread use; to be fair, almost ever single major browser update this century supports this.

Comment: I will also pass along your other requests to the right team for review.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting. I don't think the question involved anything to do with GoDaddy or configuring internal IPs with port forwarding. Just because one "should" bind their sites to local IPs, doesn't mean they can. They may not have a router capable of port forwarding and therefore may have no choice but to bind the site to an external IP.

The question asked is why their external IP (bound to the NIC) is not showing up in the IIS bindings IP select box. It is a valid question and I happen to have the same problem. I have 1 of 20 IPs not displaying in the bindings. All the others are. WTF!!!